# How to inject correctly the play.api.Configuration inside an object in play framework2.5?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice, typesafe-config

I am upgrading to play framework 2.5, I have objects that are very hard to turn them to classes in order to use dependency injection, so I used this method instead:

```
object test {
@Inject var config: Configuration = _
def portNumber = config.getInt("server.port")
}
```

However on runTime i got ***null pointer exception***, the old code used to be like this :

```
object test {
def portNumber = Play.configuration.getInt("server.port")
}
```

but it is deperecated and I must change it with DI.
and another question on the fly is it possible to the same if I have got a ***trait*** instead of an ***object***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the configuration in a Singleton, like:

```
@Singleton
class ConfigForTest @Inject()(config: Configuration) {
  test.config = config
}
```

And set from here `config` in the `test` Object.

So your `test` object looks like this:

```
object test {
   var config: Configuration = _
   def portNumber = config.getInt("server.port")
}
```

Don't forget to initialise the `Singleton` in your `Module`:

```
class Module
  extends AbstractModule {

  @Override()
  override def configure(): Unit = {

    bind(classOf[ConfigForTest])
      .asEagerSingleton()
...
```

Or as *Shweta* shows, do it without any Injection. As you have a Play app, this would be enough:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object test {
   val portNumber = ConfigFactory.load().getInt("server.port")
}
```

This takes `application.conf` direct from the Classpath.

Comment: I forgot to add it to the module / I also added a version without Injection - see my edited answer.

Comment: I will try with the binding, because I'am creating the application.conf file on the fly, that means it is a scala file

Comment: but then you must make sure that the Singleton is not called too early!

Comment: what about if I have got a Trait instead of an object?

Comment: Thanks in Stackoverflow is Upvote and accept the answer - is also faster than to write a comment;).

Comment: First never mix 2 questions in one. `trait` is a problem that it is not singleton - so how would you initialise it?

Comment: ok, please take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433087/how-to-inject-correctly-the-dbapi-inside-a-trait-in-play-framework2-5

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do is

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val restConfig = ConfigFactory.load("rest.conf") //your conf file
val pageSize = restConfig.getInt("pagesize") //the value you want from conf file
```

Comment: it did not work maybe because I 'am creating the .conf file from a scala file

Comment: In yonf folder of your play framework create a file and then try.