# How to inject correctly the DBApi inside a trait in play framework2.5?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I am upgrading to play framework 2.5 and as mentioned by play the following code needs to be with dependency injection

```
trait DataSource {
  import play.api.Play.current
  def dataSource = DB.getDataSource()}
```

is it possible to use DI with trait?

Answer (score 0):

No and Yes;).

No because you need at least one Implementation.

If you have one Implementation, the only thing is that it must be a simple Class (not a case class).

```
class MyDataSource @Inject()(val dataSource: PlayDataSource) extends DataSource
```

With `@Inject()(...)` you can inject whatever you want and for example override stuff from the `trait`.

Comment: and what is the solution for classes that extend this trait with other traits?

Comment: I don't understand your question? My answer includes a class that extends this trait.

Comment: I use this trait in extends clause and import clause, so as far as I understand I should modify the class that extends this trait with val dataSource: PlayDataSource injector?

Comment: can you see this issue with DI : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436408/how-to-inject-the-application-application-when-the-application-starts-with-pl