# How to inject the (application: Application) when the application starts with play framework 2.5?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

I'am trying to inject the application value when starting the play server in order to display something if the app in prod mode and  something else if it is in dev mode,
I created the module file that will inject eagerly the class:

```
class startModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override()
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[StartApplication]).asEagerSingleton()
}
```

also I added in the conf  file, and my start application code is :

```
@Singleton
class StartApplication @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle, app:Application) {
  def startApplicationHandler(): Unit = {
     if (app.mode == Mode.Prod) {
      Logger.info("Application in prod mode")
     } else {
      Logger.info("Application in dev mode")
  }
}
startApplicationHandler()
}
```

However when running the server I got an error :  Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application

My app.conf content is :

```
play.application.loader : "global.CustomApplicationLoader"
play.modules.enabled += "global.startModule"
play.http.errorHandler = "global.ApplicationErrorHandler"
play.http.filters = "global.AppFilters"
play.crypto.secret : "0000"
```

Comment: have you enabled the module in `application.conf`?

Comment: yeah, of course

Comment: can you add `application.conf` it to your question - I don't see any other problem